# Facebook ads api: Retrieving deleted object ids from parent node

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to retrieve the ids of deleted objects contained within the parent node/object on the facebook ads api in order to query them directly for stats (facebook only allows querying for insights by deleted object id)

For example, I'd like to get all the:

- deleted campaigns from the account node
- deleted adsets from each campaign id returned above
- deleted ads from each adset id returned above

Is there any way to get these lists?

I've attempted to use the "effective_status=deleted" param on the parent object, but it throws an error:

- "error_user_msg": "Requesting for deleted objects is not supported in this endpoint."

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, deleted objects will no longer be retrievable as a connection object. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/storing_adobjects#deleted

Stats of deleted objects will still be reported in aggregate in their parent objects. But unless you have access to deleted object id, you won't be able to get individual stats for them.

See more about how delete and archive work here: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/09/24/deleted-vs-archived/

Comment: See also about Deleted vs Archived on FB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785739/how-can-i-retrieve-a-large-number-of-deleted-campaigns-adsets-ads#comment101801124_45817257