# How can I retrieve a large number of DELETED Campaigns, Adsets, Ads?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

## Task

I'm trying to retrieve all Ad Campaign, Adsets and Ads from various accounts associated with our Business Manager.

## Issue

The specific endpoints that I'm accessing are:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/campaigns
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/adsets
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_xxxxxxxxxxxxx/ads

When I query *some* of these accounts for all Campaigns using the `filter` parameter,

```
[{'operator': 'IN',
        'field': 'ad.effective_status',
        'value': [
            'ACTIVE',
            'PAUSED',
            'DELETED',
            'PENDING_REVIEW',
            'DISAPPROVED',
            'PREAPPROVED',
            'PENDING_BILLING_INFO',
            'CAMPAIGN_PAUSED',
            'ARCHIVED',
            'ADSET_PAUSED']}]
```

the Facebook API always returns this error:

```
{"error":{"code":1,"message":"Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"}}
```

## Troubleshooting

- I've used various values for the `filter` parameter such as 1, 25, 50, 100, 500.
- I've tried limiting the date using the `date_preset` parameters (this seems irrelevant).
- I've tried limiting the queries by filtering down to individual campaigns by including `{'operator': 'IN','field':'campaign.id','value':['xxxxxxxxxxxxx']}` as an additional filter in the `filter` parameter.
- I've attempted batch requests and querying the `/insights` endpoint, but I haven't had one work yet.

## Other Details

When I only include `ACTIVE` campaigns in the filter, the query works. This has allowed me to deduce that the `DELETED` campaigns are the problem. In other words, these accounts have a ton of `DELETED` campaigns.

I'm making my requests using Postman Version 5.0.0 (5.0.0).

I imagine if I can figure out how to get the Campaigns, the Adsets and Ads will be similar. How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the API does not actually support querying for deleted objects for certain endpoints. I tried to obtain all campaigns for a certain account and this is the response.

```
Method:  GET
Path:    
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/act_XXXX/campaigns
Params:  {'effective_status': '["ACTIVE","PAUSED","DELETED","ARCHIVED"]', 'fields': 'id,name,status', 'summary': 'true'}

Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 100, 
    "is_transient": false, 
    "error_subcode": 1815001, 
    "error_user_msg": "Requesting for deleted objects is not supported in this endpoint.", 
    "error_user_title": "Cannot Request for Deleted Objects", 
    "message": "Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "fbtrace_id": "FYDwMABcwxj"
  }
}
```

After looking at the documentation I discovered this 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/storing_adobjects

And here they state

> If you keep the deleted object id, you can continue to retrieve the
>   stats or object details by individually querying the object ID.
>   However you cannot retrieve the deleted objects as a connection object
>   from a non deleted node/object.

Comment: It sucks, but I think you're right. I tried `/v4.0/act_311200999919992/campaigns?fields=adsets.limit(5000){ads.limit(5000){name},name},name&limit=5000&effective_status=['DELETED']` and got this error: **"Requesting for deleted objects is not supported in this endpoint."**

Comment: Also interesting: "DELETED" is not the same as "ARCHIVED", and when you click Delete in the FB UI, it actually sets an ad to Archived, according to https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/09/24/deleted-vs-archived/, and which I just confirmed at `/v4.0/23843599855939992?fields=name,status`.